# Multiple combinations of value in the list based on the target and count

Tags: scala, list, recursion, collections, combinations

This is my input having preset `target` for all resources and `value` for each resource and the list of one initial combination(`res`, size of `res` may be anything). So the end result should be the multiple combinations of resources to achieve the target, but the sum of values should not exceed the target, but should be nearest to the target(shown in `res1`,`res2`....resN etc)

```
case class Container(name:String,count:Long,value:Double)

val target = 742.0
val value = 250.0

val a = Container(Resource1, 1 , 250.0)
val b = Container(Resource2, 2 , 125.0)
val c = Container(Resource3, 3 , 83.33)
val d = Container(Resource4, 1 , 250.0)

val res = List(a,b,c,d)

val a1 = Container(Resource1, 2 , 125.0)
val b2 = Container(Resource2, 1 , 250.0)
val c3 = Container(Resource3, 3 , 83.33)
val d4 = Container(Resource4, 1 , 250.0)

val res1 = List(a1,b2,c3,d4) 

val a5 = Container(Resource1, 2 , 125.0)
val b6 = Container(Resource2, 1 , 250.0)
val c7 = Container(Resource3, 1 , 250.0)
val d8 = Container(Resource4, 3 , 83.33)

 val res2 = List(a5,b6,c7,d8)
```

I tried like this but getting only one combination, please anybody help in solving out this.

```
var tar: Double = target
  val listBuffer = ListBuffer[Container]()

    def doRecursion(r: String, value: Double, count: Int = 1): List[Container] = {

      if (value < tar) {
        tar = tar - value
        listBuffer += Container(r, count, value / count)
        listBuffer.toList
      } else {
        if (listBuffer.toList.nonEmpty) {

            val last = listBuffer.toList.last
            listBuffer -= last
            listBuffer += last.copy(count = last.count + 1, time = (last.time * last.count) / (last.count + 1))

            tar = target - (listBuffer.toList.map(_.time).sum)    
          doRecursion(r, value)
        }
        else {
          doRecursion(r, value / 2, count + 1)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to take a list of Containers and ensure that the sum of the value of each `Container` in the list does not exceed the value of `target` ? Do you have to divide a value by 2 or just subtract the excess?

Comment: @RobertUdah....correct but if it is exceeding, I need to increase the count and adjust.

Comment: If my answer solves the issue, do you mind marking it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Would this be closer to what you're trying to do?

```
case class Container(name:String,count:Long,value:Double)
//val target = 742.0
val target = 500.0
val value = 250.0
val a = Container("Resource1", 1 , 250.0)
val b = Container("Resource2", 2 , 125.0)
val c = Container("Resource3", 3 , 83.33)
val d = Container("Resource4", 1 , 250.0)

val cList1 = List(a,b,c,d)

val a1 = Container("Resource1", 2 , 125.0)
val b2 = Container("Resource2", 1 , 250.0)
val c3 = Container("Resource3", 3 , 83.33)
val d4 = Container("Resource4", 1 , 250.0)

val cList2 = List(a1,b2,c3,d4)

val a5 = Container("Resource1", 2 , 125.0)
val b6 = Container("Resource2", 1 , 250.0)
val c7 = Container("Resource3", 1 , 250.0)
val d8 = Container("Resource4", 3 , 83.33)

val cList3 = List(a5,b6,c7,d8)

@tailrec
def doRecursion(containerList: List[Container]): List[Container] = {
  if(containerList.map(_.value).sum <= target) containerList
  else doRecursion(containerList.map( c => Container(c.name, c.count + 1, c.value/2)))
}
doRecursion(cList1)
doRecursion(cList2)
doRecursion(cList3)
```

And I get the result:

```
res0: List[Container] = List(Container(Resource1,2,125.0), Container(Resource2,3,62.5), Container(Resource3,4,41.665), Container(Resource4,2,125.0))
res1: List[Container] = List(Container(Resource1,3,62.5), Container(Resource2,2,125.0), Container(Resource3,4,41.665), Container(Resource4,2,125.0))
res2: List[Container] = List(Container(Resource1,3,62.5), Container(Resource2,2,125.0), Container(Resource3,2,125.0), Container(Resource4,4,41.665))
```

I had commented out/reduced the old value for `target` as `doRecursion()` simply returns the original list.

Answer (score -1):

If this is work related, not a homework exercise, what you're trying to do is actually constraint programming.  A good one to use is OscaR (https://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pschaus/cp4impatient/firststeps.html).

EDIT: If it is a homework exercise, read about OscaR anyway and do something similar to how it builds and prunes its trees and you will probably be able to create your answer in that way.

Comment: This is my work related, try to use comments to convey these kind of answers.

Comment: Im sorry if you got offended but I still think I gave you a useful answer in that you are doing constraint programming and that OscaR is a good library to start with.